# Mongodb how to count how many times a field value comes?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation

let´s say I have a document of blog posts that has fields "_id, userName, age". a user could have made more than one blog post, I want to find the users that have made 4 posts.
db.blogs.aggregate([{$group: {_id: {"$userName", "age"}, : {$sum: ""eq", 3}}])

Answer (score 0):

To know how many times a field comes, use a $group stage to group by that field and add an extra field for the count using the $count operator. Then if you want to filter by that count, just add a $match stage  to filter by that new field:

```
{
  $group: {
    "_id": "$username",
    "count": {
      $count: {}
    }
  }
},
{
  $match: {
    "count": {
      $gte: 4
    }
  }
}
```

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZKrUZ9yhaGZ)

Comment: Would this work with the posts are in an array?